# Should AspNet Identity UserManager do all the work related to users and roles?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Primarily, AspNet Identity is for Authentication, but it also relies on pretty important domain entities, like Users, Roles and so on. Most of the time business logic also manipulates all these domains, at least checking if the user has the role or maybe even reading the whole list of users and giving it forward to front end.

This would be the standard DbContext implementation with AspNet Identity in Entity Framework.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

The IdentityDbContext provides those User, Role and such DbSets, so obviously you can access these domain entities as any other, but they are read-only.

So, there are two ways of accessing for example Users and Roles, either through the UserManager that exposes specific methods or through a DbContext just coding against the DbSet it self.

**Question:**
Is there anything you get more using only UserManager instead of mixing DbSets and UserManager throughtout the business logic?

One thing I would expect is that DbSet might be easier to mock for Unit testing, because for UserManager you have to mock UserStore and even more if you are using most of its features.